# How can I find replacement parts for an unknown faucet?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

In the house I bought one of the faucets is missing a hot water indicator. I have no idea on how to go about getting a replacement indicator. Anyone know where I should start?

Here's the missing piece:

[image]

And here is what it looks like on another:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My local big box store (Lowes) has a catalog of pictures in the plumbing aisle. It contains a variety of parts for the brands they carry. You don't have to know what the part is just what it looks like. You may have to bring the other cap to match it for size. If you can't find a match replacement handles will be cheaper than a new faucet.